# Time Limit Exceeded with abs() in a C++ Program

Tags: c++

I encounter a problem with the abs() in a program. When I use the code:

```
long long dvd = abs(dividend), dvs = abs(divisor);
```

it been reported "Time Limit Exceeded"

when use:

```
long long dvd = dividend, dvs = divisor;
dvd = abs(dvd);
dvs = abs(dvs);
```

everything is okay...

The full code is following:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    long long dvd = dividend, dvs = divisor;
    dvd = abs(dvd);
    dvs = abs(dvs);
    long long result = 0;

    while (dvd >= dvs) {
        long long temp = dvs;
        int i = 0;
        while (dvd >= temp) {
            temp = temp << 1;
            i++;
        }
        dvd -= dvs << (i-1);
        result += (long long)1 << (i-1);
    }

    result = ((long long)dividend > 0 ^ (long long)divisor > 0) ? -result : result;

    if (result > (1<<31) - 1)
        return (1<<31) - 1;

    return result;
  }
};
```

Could someone help to explain what happens with `abs()` here?

Comment: Are you talking about a programming contest? Can you post more code?

Comment: There's no way to know with just the tiny bit of information you've given us.

Comment: post a small complete example that shows the failure

Comment: smells like that loop never terminates. Step through with a debugger

Comment: The following full code is all right, accepted by leetcode.

Comment: `abs` is special in that some of its overloads are in `<stdlib.h>`, and some are in `<math.h>`. However, no matter which overload you're invoking it shouldn't matter (well except for `INT_MIN` value). Have you tried the two versions *repeatedly*.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but in some of this code you're being maybe a little too clever.  For example, `if (result > (1<<31) - 1)` is both likely to result in undefined behavior and is less readable than `if (result > INT_MAX)`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely the case that `abs()` is either a macro defined like:

```
#define abs(x) (((x)<0)?-(x):(x))
```

or a template similarly defined:

```
template <typename T>
T abs (T x) { return (x < 0) ? -x : x; }
```

Thus, the resulting value of `abs()` adopts the same type as its argument. For an `int` type argument, `abs(INT_MIN)` may or may not be well defined, since it might cause signed integer overflow. (Technically, signed integer overflow invokes undefined behavior.) However, on a 2s-complement system, it will likely yield `INT_MIN` itself.

---

For the following case (the one that gives you the time limit error):

```
int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    long long dvd = abs(dividend), dvs = abs(divisor);
```

If the `divisor` is `INT_MIN`, then `dvs` is likely `INT_MIN`. Thus, it is negative.

Now, later on, you have:

```
        long long temp = dvs;
        int i = 0;
        while (dvd >= temp) {
            temp = temp << 1;
            i++;
        }
```

And this is an infinite loop if `dvd` is non-negative. This is because `temp` becomes `0` and stays there.

---

The reason your "fixed" version works is because here:

```
int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    long long dvd = dividend, dvs = divisor;
    dvd = abs(dvd);
    dvs = abs(dvs);
```

You have changed the type of the argument to `abs()` to be a `long long`, initialized by an `int`. So, if `dvs` is `(long long)INT_MIN`, then `abs(dvs)` is `-(long long)INT_MIN`, a positive number so long as `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long long)`.